# want to substract 5.30 hours from a Date javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to subtract 5.30 hours from a date, for example, I have a date:

```
Fri Jan 15 2016 00:00:00
```

after subtraction, it should be something like,

```
Thu Jan 14 2016 19:30:00
```

How I can achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are both times in local time? If so, is it ok to return 4 1/2 hours or 6 1/2 hours diff if the time interval overlaps a DST shift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
var date = new Date("Fri Jan 15 2016 00:00:00");
date.setHours(date.getHours()-5);
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()-30);
```

Comment: @Bigalow added the same.

Comment: @gurvinder372 IT WORKS LIKE CHARM AND YOU ARE MY HERO :)